# Firebase Cloud Messaging - MESSAGE_DELIVERED Event Not Appearing in BigQuery Exported Data After Completing Delivery Metrics Setup

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, web-push

I have just written a small app to handle push notifications via [FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) (both client & server API).

Also, I have used [Google Cloud BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) to have more detailed logs about how I'm handling push notification flow and how FCM behaves with each message sent by my app.

According to [BigQuery data export guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios#bigquery-data-export), I have enabled BigQuery in my FCM console and completed all the necessary steps.

As you already know, you need to handle push notifications in both foreground (using your SDK) and background (using [Service Worker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)).

I'm using:

- Vanilla JS & Node.js
- [FCM client SDK](https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-messaging.js) version 9.8.4 (loaded by CDN)
- [FCM admin node SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node) version ^10

I'm sending notifications as [Data message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#data_messages).

**Here is my Service Worker script:**

```js
import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-app.js";
import {
  getMessaging,
  onBackgroundMessage,
  experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled as _firebaseExperimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled,
} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.8.4/firebase-messaging-sw.js";

(function (self, initializeData) {
  const app = initializeApp({ ...initializeData.MyFirebaseCredentials });

  self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
    self.skipWaiting();
  });

  self.addEventListener("notificationclick", (event) => {
    // open the notification
  });

  messaging = getMessaging(app);
  onBackgroundMessage(messaging, (payload) => {
    // ...
    self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
  });

  const experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled = async (
    messaging,
    enable
  ) => {
    console.log(
      "Big Query - SetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled",
      "Setting delivery metrics exported to bigQuery..."
    );

    const bqFn = async (msg, en) => {
      return _firebaseExperimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled(
        msg,
        en
      );
    };

    return bqFn(messaging, enable)
      .then(() =>
        console.log("Big Query- SetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled", "Enabled")
      )
      .catch((err) =>
        console.error(
          "Big Query",
          "Unable to SetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled",
          { err }
        )
      );
  };
  experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled(messaging, true);
})(self, { ...Config });
```

Also I have enabled BQ in my foreground SDK using my `experimentalSetDeliveryMetricsExportedToBigQueryEnabled()` function.

The issue is that I'm only receiving the `MESSAGE_ACCEPTED` event in my BigQuery dashboard, and there is no way to track which messages have been delivered completely (`MESSAGE_DELIVERED` event), as [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/understand-delivery?platform=ios#what-data-exported) says. I also haven't found any proper solution related to this.

Can anybody help me resolve this issue?